# Changing time format in ruby

Tags: ruby, datetime

This is what I want to do:

`Time.at(1403592945)` returns
2014-06-24 **12:25:45 +0530**

How do I convert this to:
2014-06-24 **06:55:45**

How do I do that in ruby?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for UTC time.

```
Time.at(1403592945).utc
```

Comment: Yes. And if OP wants a *string representation* without the `" UTC"` then: `Time.at(1403592945).utc.to_s[0..-5]` (or equiv).  It shouldn't be surprising, but I think it's important to note that:  `Time.at(1403592945) == Time.at(1403592945).utc`